# Is there a fix for SSL errors in visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssl

I am a student learning python, and I am working with pulling information from webpages. If I try to run this program that pulls information from a live earthquake feed I get a SSL error (more specifics down below.) There is no errors with the code that I am aware of, as I am following along with a teacher on an online course.

I have tried running both the Install Certificates command and the Update Shell Profile command, neither work. I am coding in python 3.7.2 in visual studio code, I am also on a Mac. The error code I am getting is this:

```
Exception has occurred: URLError
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
```

I also got this message in my terminal:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi-2019.3.9.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

I tried typing that into the terminal and it says command not found. I am using a school computer so certain things are blocked, and maybe that's part of the issue, I don't really know. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request 
import json

def printResults(data):
  theJSON = json.loads(data)

  if "title" in theJSON["metadata"]:
    print(theJSON["metadata"]["title"])

  count = theJSON["metadata"]["count"]
  print (str(count) + " events recorded")

def main():
  urlData = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_day.geojson"

  webUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
  print ("result code: " + str(webUrl.getcode()))
  if (webUrl.getcode() == 200):
    data = webUrl.read()
    printResults(data)
  else: 
    print("Received error, cannot parse results")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

If you have a solution, remember I am a student in first semester of computer science, so explain it simply please.